# Select USB flash drive where the drive letter changes

Tags: powershell

I want to run a script from a USB drive that installs software on the computer the script is run on.

The problem is one of my programs is on the USB drive itself, but the drive letter changes on every computer I plug it into so the path for the file also changes.

Is there a way I can get the script to check what drive letter the USB drive has been assigned?

```
$out = "Z:\Pc\Powershell Script for maskiner utenfor domenet\Software\SMART.msi"
Start-Process -filePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $out /quiet /norestart /l c:\SMARTinstallog.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PSv3+ you can use `$PSScriptRoot` as this contains the fully-qualified path to the directory that contains the script file.

If your script and software locations were:

- `Z:\Pc\Powershell Script for maskiner utenfor domenet\script.ps1`
- `Z:\Pc\Powershell Script for maskiner utenfor domenet\Software\SMART.msi`

`$PSScriptRoot` would be `Z:\Pc\Powershell Script for maskiner utenfor domenet` as this is the root folder for the script.

Using this your command would be:

```
$out = "$PSScriptRoot\Software\SMART.msi"
Start-Process -filePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $out /quiet /norestart /l c:\SMARTinstallog.txt"
```